# Optional chaining key?.key is not being accepted in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, mobile-safari

I recently learned this technique of putting a "?" when trying to read the inners of an object. It tests if the part I'm trying to reach is truthy, and handles the case of it not being. It's really useful to avoid crashes in my applications.

```js
var obj1 = {
    key1: undefined
}

console.log(obj1.key1.key2); // Throws error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key2')
console.log(obj1.key1?.key2); // Doesn't throw error. Just returns undefined
```

However, it's not working in Safari (the mobile one, at least). I'm getting the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'` right on the line where I use the question mark technique.

How is this technique (inserting this question mark) called? Doesn't Safari accept it?

Comment: Which version of Safari on iOS? Should be supported since 13.4 per https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_operators_optional_chaining. Also note that's JavaScript, not JSON.

Comment: [That's JavaScript, not JSON](https://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: That's it then: I was testing in Safari Mobile 12. Sad to know it's a feature I can't use, since a lot of people are still in Safari Mobile 12. Thanks, though.